# Decidable language closed under complement

Tags: computer-science, computability

Why are decidable languages closed under complement?

So if L is decidable why is the complement of L also decidable.

Comment: If you have a decision mechanism that always correctly returns *yes* or *no* to the question *Is w in L?*, interchanging the outputs (turning *yes* to *no* and vice versa) gives you a decision mechanism for the complement of $L$.

Comment: It's a simple result from the definition of a decidable language.

Answer (score 1):

(To get this off the unanswered list, I’m converting my comment to an answer.)

If you have a decision mechanism that always correctly returns *yes* or *no* to the question

> $\hspace{5cm}$Is $w$ in $L\,$?,

interchanging the outputs — i.e., turning *yes* to *no* and *no* to *yes* — gives you a decision mechanism for the complement of $L$.